# matplotlib.pyplot.his and basic python: I can't understand the difference between the to examples

Tags: python, matplotlib, arraylist

I can't understand the difference between the following two examples.
In the first one it creates tons of data but in the other one, it doesn't and I'm not sure why.
`grah` and `labsh` might be arrays and that might explain the data contained in them.
I can't really find it out - appreciate your help

example 1:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

grah = 50
labsh = 60

plt.hist([grah, labsh], stacked = True, color =["r"])
plt.show()
```

example 2:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gra = 500
labs = 500

grah = 28 + 4 * np.random.randn(gra)
labsh = 24 + 4 * np.random.randn(labs)

plt.hist([grah, labsh], stacked = True, color =["r", "b" ])
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's not really clear at which point you have the problem. In the first example you create a histogram of the two numbers 50 and 60. In the second example you create two histogram from two arrays which each have 500 elements. Of course those are fundamentally different. But I guess you should clearly explain what you are expecting and in how far this is not met by the code you show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example: 
`grah` and `labsh` are just values. It just plots the histogram of the values `[50,60]` in the *red* color. While on the other hand, in the second example,

[np.random.randn(*size*)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html) Returns a sample (or samples) from the “standard normal” distribution.

In the following code:

```
grah = 28 + 4 * np.random.randn(gra)
labsh = 24 + 4 * np.random.randn(labs)
```

`grah` is normally distributed with ***mu*= 28** and ***variance=4*** with size of *500* (`gra`) which means that it will generate *500* sample.

And

`labsh` is normally distributed with ***mu*= 24** and ***variance=4*** and  size of *500* too.

Also, similar function to `np.random.randn()` is `random.standard_normal`.
Similar, but takes a tuple as its argument.

Good Luck!